# How to individually set disabled Back- and Forecolor for elements

Tags: java, jframe, jtextfield, jcheckbox, disabled-control

i am working on a project where every Element on Frame has to be ReadOnly, but there is a SearchMode where the Object should be not ReadOnly. So it has to switch between those two modes

my Problem now is that the JTextField has a Property DisabledTextColor, DisabledForeColor and DisabledBackColor, but somehow JCheckbox does not have such propertys

so how can i change the BackColor and ForeColor of a CheckBox like i want it?

And is there a  way to change the disabled Borderstyle of a JTextField?

Practically i just want the items to look like they are editable, but they are ReadOnly, is this possible, if yes how?

Greetings Kevin

Comment: I suspect you probably want to make use of a modal Dialog or JDialog, rather than disabling your each of your components while making them appear enabled.

Comment: can you name an example on how that would make it easier for me to accomplish what i want?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html .  I quote: “When a modal Dialog is visible, it blocks user input to all other windows in the program.”

Comment: why would i want a dialog instead of a Combobox? i want all thos elements to be on one frame i can't use a dialog for every single Combobox Element

Comment: I can’t see your user interface, so I don’t know what you’re doing.  You didn’t explain why you want to disable everything.  I was guessing that you wanted the user’s attention to be only on one specific set of fields, for which a modal dialog is usually appropriate.  Reading your question again, I wonder if setting your JTextFields to be [non-editable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setEditable-boolean-) would suffice?

Comment: i already figured out how to do it with UIManager, there i can set a diabledbackground and disabledforeground for JTextField and JComboBox, but i still need to figure out how to apply this to JRadioButton and JCheckBox    and i did describe what i want to do, there is a frame where there are many elements in an overview of personal data f.e. and this data should be readonly, but that grey tone when disabling the elements is just ugly and not what i want